# Passing a component to another component in react

Tags: reactjs, atomic-design

I am creating a small library of component and I have a table component and my task is make it modular and generic so it can be modified later

Now Table by nature is a container component that is it can contain different various other small component that I am building in a library.

**What I Want to Know?**

Is the below approach correct way to pass component to other component? if not than what is the correct way or better way of doing it?

**What I am Doing**

table have many props but 3 main props are :

`colName` which is an array of string passing the table column name of each column

`data` is an array which contains array for each row.

`dataComponent` (remains undefined if you want to display data as normal text data) which is an array of component(the one's which I defined in the library) to be used for a specific column for each row

**Too Much of talk about row and column and code**

Now Here is The sample code:

```
     const User = [
          <React.Fragment>
            <span className="userinfo">
              <MUserIcon user_name={"dummy1"} profile_type={"facebook"} />
            </span>
            <span className="userinfo">
              <MLink
                link_href={"https://www.facebook.com"}
                link_content={"dummy1"}
              />
            </span>
          </React.Fragment>,

          <React.Fragment>
            <span className="userinfo">
              <MUserIcon user_name={"dummy2"} profile_type={"instagram"} />
            </span>
            <span className="userinfo">
              <MLink
                link_href={"https://www.instagram.com"}
                link_content={"dummy2"}
              />
            </span>
          </React.Fragment>,

          <React.Fragment>
            <span className="userinfo">
              <MUserIcon
                user_name="imawebdev"
                profile_type="linkedin"
                user_img_src={pro_pic}
              />,
            </span>
            <span className="userinfo">
              <MLink
                link_href={"https://www.linkedin.com"}
                link_content={"imawebdev"}
              />
            </span>
          </React.Fragment>
        ];






return (
          <div className="App">
            <MTable
              title="Demo Table"
              colsName={["Account Name", "Queued", "Errors"]}
              data={[["imawebdev", 5, 0], ["dummy1", 4, 3], ["dummy2", 4, 0]]}
              dataComponent={[User]}
            />
          </div>
        );
      }
```

The above code has a `dataComponent` that passes component for `colName` "Account Name" which is composed of user avatar component(which I built as a part of the library) called `MUserIcon` and same can be said for `MLink` which is a hyperlink component.

Answer (score 2):

In React you can use child components. Instead of using your `dataComponent` prop, you could structure it like this:

```
<MTable /* props here */>
   {User}
</MTable>
```

And then, in `MTable`, instead of using `props.dataComponent`, you can use `props.children`, which will still give you your `User` all the same.

You can also define `User` as a component itself, so it would look a bit more consistent:

```
const user User = () => [ /* your array of fragments here */ ]

<MTable /* props here */>
   <User />
</MTable>
```